# Time Complexity of This Loop

Tags: c, loops, time-complexity

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
 int j = 2;
 while (j<i)
    j = j * j;
}
```

I think its n*log(n) as the first loop iterates `n` times, but I'm not sure about the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question has all the hallmarks of homework, I'll not give a final answer outright, but instead give you some guidance on how to get there yourself.

You're right that you need a bound on the number of iterations of the inner loop to determine the overall bound.  To evaluate that, consider the form of the values `j` will take in successive iterations of that loop: 2, 4, 16, 256, etc..  It is useful to write a closed formula for that number in terms of the number of loop iterations.

Clearly the sequence consists of increasing powers of 2, but not linearly increasing powers.  We have 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>4</sup>, 2<sup>8</sup>, ....  At this point, though, you ought to recognize the pattern, and be able to write a formula for the value of `j` after the `k`th iteration of the inner loop, for *k* = 0, 1, 2, 3 ....  Let *Inner*(*k*) designate that formula.  (The specific formula is left as an exercise.)

So how many iterations of that inner loop will be performed for a given value of `i`?  Variable `j` takes the values of *Inner*(*k*) as that loop iterates, and the loop terminates when `j >= i`, so the number of iterations is the least value *k* such that *Inner*(*k*) is at least as large as `i`, and the maximum number of iterations of that loop is the least *k* such that *Inner*(*k*) is at least `n`.  Now, estimate `n` to be *Inner*(*k*), and solve for *k*.

The remaining details are, again, left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you! it's homework you're right :) I think i got it: the growth is 2, 4, 16... or 2^2^0, 2^2^1, 2^2^2... the pattern is 2^2^k with k as the number of iterations. the  loop stops when 2^2^k is greater than or equals n times. so: 2^2^k >= n [...] --> k >= log(log(n)). so the run time of the whole code is n*log(log(n)).

Comment: @mosh, yes, that's how I analyze it.